# How does Raspbian depend on Python2.x?

Tags: raspbian, python

I've written a Python3.x code on a PC (win 7) in order to read out temperature data from an external measurement unit (using basically pyserial & Matplotlib). I want to port this program on a RasPi.
By installing packages I got some trouble with pip: I assume it is because both Python2.x and 3.x is on my RasPi. So I decided to remove Python2.x .
How dependent is Raspbian on Python2.x? 
What kind of troubles could it cause if I remove Python2.x?

Comment: Can you use [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org) to set up your environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A crude list of the packages that depend on python 2 on my Raspberry Pi is given by:

```
$ awk '/^Package: / {package=$2;} /^Depends: .*python .*2\./ {print package;}' /var/lib/dpkg/status | fmt
python-pkg-resources python-dbus python-tk python-tz python-pyparsing
python-gi python-support python-dev python-cairo python-scipy
python-wimpiggy python-gobject-2 python-rpi.gpio xpra python-glade2
python-matplotlib python-dateutil devscripts python-gtk2 python-jinja2
python-numpy python-pyspatialite python-markupsafe python-imaging
python-pygame idle
```

This looks like it has some important ones to me. I wouldn't even try.

Are you sure that the packages you installed with `pip` weren't already in the repos?

Comment: python3-pyserial, and matplotlib wasn't installed on Raspi. I managed to install pyserial.
Is there any difference between Win and RasPi serial outputs? I can use the following command only from win:
ser.write(bytearray('remote\r\n', encoding='ascii'))

Comment: I said, these are the ones installed on *my* Raspberry Pi; yours will be different. I certainly wouldn't want to break devscripts by removing Python 2.